# Show : $(-1)^{n}n^{-\tan\left(\tfrac{\pi}{4}+\tfrac{1}{n} \right)}=\tfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\tfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show that :
>   $$(-1)^{n}n^{-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$$

My proof:

> Note that :
>   \begin{align*}
> e^{x}&=1+x+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{2}\right)\quad (x\to 0)\\
> \tan(x)&=x+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{3} \right)\\
> \tan(a+b)&=\dfrac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}\\
> x^{a}&=e^{a\ln(x)}\quad (x>0)
> \end{align*}
>   then:

- $-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)=\left(1-\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \right)^{-1}$
- $\dfrac{1}{n}  \underset{ \overset { n \rightarrow +\infty } {} } {\longrightarrow }0$
- $\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3}} \right)\right)^{-1}=\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right) \right)^{-1}=n\left( 1-\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\right)$

Thus :

\begin{align*}
(-1)^{n}n^{-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)}&=(-1)^{n}e^{-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)\ln(n)} \\
&=(-1)^{n}\exp\left[-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)\ln(n)\right]\\
&=(-1)^{n}\exp\left[\left(1-\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \right)^{-1}\ln(n)\right]\\
&=(-1)^{n}\exp\left[\left(1-\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3}} \right)\right)^{-1} \right)^{-1}\ln(n)\right]\\
\end{align*}

I'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we note that $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)$ can be expanded as

$$\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)&=\frac{1+\tan(1/n)}{1-\tan(1/n)}\\\\
&=1+\frac2n +\frac2{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
\end{align}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
e^{-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)\log(n)}&=e^{-\left(1+\frac2n +\frac2{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
\right)\log(n)}\\\\
&=\frac1n\,e^{-\left(\frac{2\log(n)}n +\frac{2\log(n)}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^3}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=\frac1n\,\left(1-2\frac{\log(n)}{n}-2\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1n +O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$(-1)^n\,n^{-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)}=(-1)^n\frac1n +O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: would you elaborate  that please $\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)&=\frac{1+\tan(1/n)}{1-\tan(1/n)}\\\\
&=1+\frac2n +\frac2{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
\end{align}$

Comment: Recall that $\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan(x)+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}$, and $\tan(\pi/4)=1$.  That leads to the first equality.  Then note that $\tan(x)=x+O(x^3)$  and $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+O(z^3)$.  Now, let $z=x+O(x^3)$, apply the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and multiply by $1+x+O(x^3)$ to get $(1+x)^2+x^2+O(x^3)$.

Comment: why we chose $O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)$ instead of $O\left(\frac{\log^{2}(n)}{n^3}\right)$ what is the idea that leads us to chose exactly $O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)$

Comment: What converges faster; $\log^2(n)/n^3$, or $\log(n)/n^2$?

Comment: of course $\log(n)/n^2$ so everytime should i check what is the terme which converge faster am i right ?

Comment: Not quite.  Actually, $\log^2(n)/n^3$ converges faster than $\log(n)/n^2$.  To see this, we form the ratio $\frac{\log^2(n)/n^3}{\log(n)/n^2}=\log(n)/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: so professor what is the best way that  let me know what should i chose

Comment: @Educ First, I am no longer a professor; I left academics in 1996.  Please call me Mark.  Second, I don't know what you mean by "choose."  The order of the error term is the term than approaches zero the next slowest after $1/n$.  And that term is $\log(n)/n^2$.  That is all there is to it. -Mark

Comment: nice to meet you mark for example when iarrive to that equality $\left(\dfrac1n-2\dfrac{\log(n)}{n^2}-2\dfrac{\log(n)}{n^3}+O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^3}\right)\right)\\$ how can i know that i should chose $O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)$ and not other terms

Comment: Well, can you see which terms go to zero the most slowly?

Comment: Mark do you any good book that help me to understand well

Comment: the terms which go to zero the most slowly is $\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}$

Comment: After $1/n$, yes.

Comment: why we can't take expansion up to  $2$ $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+O(z^2)$ instead of $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+O(z^3)$