# nature of the series $\sum (-1)^{n}n^{-\tan\left(\tfrac{\pi}{4}+\tfrac{1}{n} \right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I would like to study the nature of the following serie:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\ (-1)^{n}n^{-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)} $$

we can use simply this question :

### [Show : $(-1)^{n}n^{-\tan\left(\tfrac{\pi}{4}+\tfrac{1}{n} \right)}=\tfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\tfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860370/show-1nn-tan-left-tfrac-pi4-tfrac1n-right-tfrac-1)

$$\sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^{n}n^{-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\sum_{n\geq 1} \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right) $$

Since :

- Alternating harmonic series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ is convergent
- $\sum_{n\geq 1} \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right) $ is convergent since $\left|  \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)\right|\leq \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}$

thus $\sum_{n\geq 0}\ (-1)^{n}n^{-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)} $ is convergent

**My question :**

- Why we can't take expansion up to  $2$ $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+O(z^2)$ instead of $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+O(z^3)$

\begin{align}
 \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)&=\left(1+\tan(1/n)\right)\left(1-\tan(1/n)\right)^{-1}\\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right) \\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{-1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)^{2} \right) \right) \\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) \right) \\
&=1-\frac{1}{n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)
 \end{align}

then :

\begin{align}
e^{-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)\log(n)}&=e^{\left(-1-\frac{1}{n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\right)\log(n)}\\\\
&=\frac1n\,e^{\left(-\frac{\log(n)}n^{2}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=\frac1n\,\left(1-\frac{\log(n)}{n^{2}}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)+O\left(\frac{\log^{2}(n)}{n^4}\right) \right)\\\\
&=\frac1n +O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^3}\right)
\end{align}
$$(-1)^{n}e^{-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)\log(n)}=(-1)^{n}\frac1n +O\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}\log(n)}{n^3}\right) $$
and since  $\sum O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^3}\right)$ and $(-1)^{n}\frac1n$ are convergent

i prove that the series is conevrgent only by using expansion up to 2 why we can't take it

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake in

\begin{align}
 \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)&=\left(1+\tan(1/n)\right)\left(1-\tan(1/n)\right)^{-1}\\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right) \\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{-1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)^{2} \right) \right) \\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) \right) \\
&=1-\frac{1}{n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)
 \end{align}

It should be

\begin{align}
 \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)&=\left(1+\tan(1/n)\right)\left(1-\tan(1/n)\right)^{-1}\\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\right)^{-1} \\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)^{2} \right) \right) \\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) \right) \\
&=1+\frac{2}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)
 \end{align}

That is, you effectively wrote

\begin{align}
{1+x\over1-x}&=(1+x)(1-x)^{-1}\\
&=(1+x)(1-x+x^2+\cdots)
\end{align}

instead of

\begin{align}
{1+x\over1-x}&=(1+x)(1-x)^{-1}\\
&=(1+x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)
\end{align}

(It looks like you also omitted the exponent $-1$ when changing from $(1-\tan(1/n))$ to its Taylor expansion, but I think that was just a typo.)

Comment: but you didn't answer my question, With your resultat we got $$=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}-\dfrac{2(-1)^{n}\ln(n)}{n^{2}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{3}}\right) $$ is this also prove the convergent of series if that not is it proof the reason that we should take expansion up to 3 am i right

Comment: @Educ, you do not need to go beyond the $\ln(n)/n^2$ term.  It "swallows" the higher-order stuff.  That is, $\ln(n)/n^2+O(\ln(n)/n^3)=O(\ln(n)/n^2)$.  You can, of course, use the more exact expression in your comment; it's just that you don't need to.

Comment: so it will be $$=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}\right)$$ then is conevrgent ??

Comment: @Educ, yes.  It's what's highlighted in blue in your posting.

Comment: so we got the same resulat even we used expansion up to 2 instead of 3 so there is no difference

Comment: @Educ, yes, in terms of showing convergence here, it doesn't matter if you stop at two terms (as the blue solution does) or go up to three terms, as you did.  The only thing wrong in your approach was that you made a mistake in the expansion that caused the second term to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Without digging into asymptotics, the original series is simply convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), since $\{(-1)^n\}$ has bounded partial sums and

$$ n^{-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{n}\right)} = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1+\tan(1/n)}{1-\tan(1/n)}}}$$
is decreasing towards zero for any $n\geq 3$.

Comment: thanks but the aim of my question is to understand the right using of  asymptotics to prove the convergent of such a series

Comment: Mosquito nuking, ok :D